# Aren't the values supposed to sum up for each bar?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was expecting for example the `F` bar to have `8+9=17` and not only `9` (the last value for `F`).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'F']
y = [ 5  , 8  , 7,   9,   9,   2,   7,   8,   8,   9 ]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.bar(x, y)

plt.show();
```

Can someone explain the logic please ?

[image]

Comment: No, they're not *supposed* to add up. `ax.bar` just iterates `x,y` and plots the bars in order. In the given plot, you actually have 4 bars at `D` tick and 2 bars at `F` ticks. They overlap one another. If you want to plot the sum, you need to add them up yourself.

Comment: Thanks @QuangHoang, I understand now the logic because you made it very clear. Thanks for your time.

Comment: To get sums with a seaborn barplot: `sns.barplot(x=x, y=y, ci=None, estimator=sum)`

Comment: I gave it a try and I genuinely appreciate the trick! Whoever made this seaborn (maybe is you) seems to have a solid understanding of what a lambda enthusiast like me needs. Thanks @JohanC.

Comment: Seaborn is Michael Waskom's magical brainchild and ongoing effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's normal, the bars are superimposed. See for example changing the opacity:

```
ax.bar(x, y, alpha=0.1)
```

[image]

You can use [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) to group the values:

```
pd.Series(y).groupby(x).sum().plot.bar()
```

Output:

[image]

Or in pure python:

```
out = {}
for X, Y in zip(x, y):
    out[X] = out.get(X, 0) + Y

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(*zip(*out.items()))
```

[image]

Comment: The opacity thing has quickly cleared up the confusion I had. Thank you so much.